# Java - Prevent breaking within method

Tags: java, debugging

Is there a way to prevent debuggers from hitting automatic breakpoints within a method (like with an annotation)? I remember there is an attribute in C# that did this. I'd prefer to do this from the code rather than within the IDE.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. What is an automatic breakpoint compared to a manual one. Why can't you just disable the breakpoint?

Comment: Yes, agree with @Fabian — explain your question better. _"Is there a way to prevent ..."_ is your proposed solution to some problem you're trying to solve — explain the problem. For example, if you're trying to stop debuggers from breaking in your code as a "security measure", forget it. If it's a conditional breakpoint as Yishai suggests then tell us that.

Comment: I'm trying to prevent debuggers from hitting exception breakpoints (a feature some IDE's have, to automatically break on an exception).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't have code that interacts with the debugger in an official way (last I heard), however many debuggers have something called a conditional breakpoint, where it will only stop if some variable or field evaluates to a specified value.

So you could have your code change a value (like a constant) and set the breakpoint conditionally that way.

Note that conditional breakpoints are generally a performance hit.

Comment: That's just what I needed. Apparently Java can't interact with the debugger from the code like .NET can.